# Wait for Geocoordinatewatcher finish before continue with execution

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, gps

I am making a app that inserts the gps coordinates on a db and when i run on the emulator it runs fine but when i actually move to the WP itself its just records the 2 first digits,like it records -19 for latitude witch is too vague for what i need,i need at least 3 decimal places ,but if i put the coordinates to a text block it show up fine. What i think its happening its that the app is inserting before the gps finishes tracking the coordinates so i need to set it to where the app would wait until its finished to insert, but i don't know how to do it, i tried put a system.threading.thread.sleep but it just freeze the app.One more thing the method to insert on the database is a asynchronous method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
watcher.MovementThreshold = 0.5;
```

Setting the Accuracy to High and the MovementThreshold to 0.5 (event will be fired when someone moves 0.5 meters) should give you the most accurate results for tracking the position.